# how do we calculate runtime of Z3 sat solver

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, z3, z3py

I am using z3py to solve a set of equations. How would I calculate the runtime order of it?
It has bitvecs variables which need to be satisfied in a set of linear equations. The documentation and the guide does not give a way to calculate the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking for the (worst-case) *time complexity* of the used solvers? If so, I don't think that you'll be able to get a good answer: it depends on the (combination of) logic(s) into which your problem falls, e.g. QF_BV or UFNIA, and then on the ((semi) decision) procedures that the solver implements for that (combination of) logic(s).

Have a look at papers from the Z3 authors (https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki/Publications) - they might provide some details.